# SQL 'OR' causing time out

Tags: sql, timeout, conditional-statements, union

Locally, this query runs fine (<1sec) but on the clients side it takes around 3mins (With a different Execution Plan). 
I've rebuilt the indexes, stats, etc. This decreased the time to 2:15. 
 After investigating I found out that the issue revolves around the or statement beginning on the line 
`AND (a.p = '123456789' or ...` If I restructure the query to use a union instead, the query takes <1sec. 
 **So what is it about this 'or' that causes the clients time to jump 2+ minutes?**

```
select *
from foo_main A with(nolock)
where a.i = a.i
and (IsNull(A.v, '0') = '1')
and (IsNull(A.d, '') = 'CODE_B')
and A.c in ('CODE_B')
AND (a.p = '123456789' or
a.p IN (SELECT DISTINCT f.ui
    FROM foo_faculty f
    LEFT JOIN foo_unit ff ON (f.ui = ff.ui)
    LEFT JOIN unit u ON (ff.ui = u.ui AND
        f.c = u.c),
    foo_Personnel p, foo_System s, unit u1
    WHERE s.P = p.P
    AND s.s = 'G'
    AND s.R = 'R4'
    AND p.ui = '1q2w3e4r5t6y'
    AND p.ui = u1.ui
    AND p.i = u1.i
    AND u.i = u1.i
    AND u.dI LIKE u1.DI + '%' COLLATE
    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS))
order by lname, fname
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Sorry I should have mentioned before, the `select *` is not part of the original code. I changed it to minimize the amount of code so everyone could find the or statement more easily.

Comment: 1) select * will bring all columns/data to display and will eat a lot of time.
2) when using left join probably you're only after of the data which is not present on the right table which you will then have to specify your filter within the left join statement and not the where clause.
3) and probably your where clause should filter only null values from the right table which in principle you would like to know if you don't have any matches from the left table.
4) and try explicitly using Inner joins (ON) rather than to it joined through the where clause. (join optimization)

Answer (score 0):

Use JOINS instead of IN () clause.